# Django - (OperationalError) FATAL: Ident authentication failed for user "username"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've written a simple sqlalchemy-django model, according to this manual: http://lethain.com/replacing-django-s-orm-with-sqlalchemy/, which worked for me pretty well.
My Django is connected to a remote postgresql database, with this settings:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': 'wetlab_dev',                               # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
    'USER': 'limlim',                                 # Not used with sqlite3.
    'PASSWORD': '',                                     # Not used with sqlite3.
    'HOST': 'cab-27',                                   # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
    'PORT': '',                                         # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

It worked for me a few days ago, but now when I try to load the 'homepage' again, it shows me the following error message:

```
(OperationalError) FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "limlim"
```

The sqlalchemy engine-configuration is:

```
CONNECTION_STR = 'postgresql://limlim:@cab-27/wetlab_dev'

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(CONNECTION_STR)
```

It seems like I haven't changed anything that is related to the database configurations, but still I get this error message.
Also, when I try to connect to the database on the remote server with my username, I succeed doing it, so I guess it's not a problem of permissions for my username to get to this database.

What can be done to overcome this error?

Comment: You should probable look at some logs... There are plenty of reasons why the Django app cannot connect to the postgreslq server..

Comment: @Tisho do you think this is a database problem, or a code problem? I've added the engine configuration lines.

Comment: Seems like a db configuration problem - you actually can connect to the DB, but it rejects your credentials. As you say this had worked before, and if you haven't made changes in code - so it appears that someone probably messed something in the DB server...

Comment: @Tisho Yeah, thanks. It indeed was something that the system people fixed for me.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your `pg_hba.conf` is configured to use 'ident' authentication for connections from localhost (127.0.0.1). You need it to be changed to `md5` for your database and user combination.

Comment: After changing  :  sudo systemctl restart postgresql

Answer (score 10):

@Craig is right, have to update the authentication method of the database user in the file pg_hba.conf, here what I've done:

`sudo nano /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`

Go to the bottom of the file, then change the method from ident to md5 on the IPv4 and IPv6 rows:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5  # <- here
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5  # <- and here
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 ident
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: That's perfect. It works and it's secure.

Answer (score 3):

```
  local   all             all                                     peer

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust < from ident to trust 
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust < i changed this from ident to trust 
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

Don't forget to restart postgresql:

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Error, only to resolve in my case instead of `md5` I used `trust`. This is because 1) Django needs SELECT, INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE permissions and 2) using the postgres user does not require a password.