# authentication failed when I use postgresql with django

Tags: django, linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2, pycharm

My environment

OS: AWS linux
python 3.7
psql (PostgreSQL) 13.3

```
$ pip freeze
asgiref==3.4.1
aws-cfn-bootstrap==2.0
Django==3.2.7
docutils==0.14
lockfile==0.11.0
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
pystache==0.5.4
python-daemon==2.2.3
pytz==2021.1
simplejson==3.2.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
```

I am trying to use PostgreSQL with Django.

I changed setting.py like below:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I created a password for PostgreSQL and I successfully logged in
as this user.

```
$ sudo su - postgres 
Last failed login: Sun Sep 26 18:21:57 JST 2021 on pts/4
There were 6 failed login attempts since the last successful login.
-bash-4.2$ psql
Password for user postgres: 
psql (13.3)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# postgres=# \l
                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 dbname    | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres+
           |          |          |             |             | username=CTc/postgres
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

However, when I tried to execute this:

```
$ python3 manage.py runserver
```

I got this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

pg_hba.conf looked like this first:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5 
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

I changed like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5  
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5  
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 ident
```

However, either way does not work and still same error.

I am not sure what the problem is and would like to know how I can fix this.

Comment: What does your `pg_hba.conf` look like?

Comment: @tink I edited my post and add that info!

Comment: You may have edited the `pg_hba.conf` ... I don't know by what means Django talks to postgres, though.  You connecting locally might work via the socket (peer), while Django uses tcp to localhost? In that case the question is how you set the password for the user - did you 'ALTER .... WITH *ENCRYPTED* PASSWORD' ?

Comment: @tink
I think I set the password by 'CREATE USER USERNAME WITH PASSWORD 'PASSWORD';'

Comment: Now that would explain why MD5 fails ... btw, did you restart postgres after the changes?

Comment: @tink Should I set the password by 'ALTER .... WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD' I think I restarted by 'sudo systemctl restart postgresql'

Comment: The restart sounds right, and yes, with MD5 you need to use `WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237617/discussion-between-tink-and-irene).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the password for the user by 'ALTER .... WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD' ?
And then the problem was solved!

Answer (score 0):

Your database name is "postgres", you can see on psql bash (postgres=#), but you setup it to "dbname" on settings

Comment: I made a database named "dbname" as well.

Comment: Have you tried change authentication method on pg_hba.conf file? Changing "Ident" to "md5"? Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64596782/13118713

Comment: As I added above, I changed them.

Answer (score 0):

You are configured to use `ident` authentication, not password. Setting a password for the user does not change that--the password assigned will just sit there unused.  If you want to use password authentication, you need to change pg_hba.conf to specify it, either `md5` or `"scram-sha-256"`.

Alternatively, you could learn how to use `ident` correctly, if that is what your framework wants you to do.

Comment: I changed pg_hba.conf, but it does not work :(
I added how my pg_hba.conf, could you please check that?